# I would like to start my app every 1 minute BootReciever android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I would like to start my app every 1 minute BootReciever android

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
{
    Context mContext;
    public MyCountDownTimer(Context context, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Somma.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(i);


    }


    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        //We know that the last onTick() happens at 2000ms remaining (skipping the last 1000ms tick for some reason, so just throw in this if statement.
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    new MyCountDownTimer(context, 60000, 60000).start();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Chat.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,  0, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60); // first time
    long frequency= 60 * 1000; // in ms
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), frequency, pendingIntent);


}

public boolean isAppForground(Context mContext) {

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(mContext.getPackageName())) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: so what is your problem ?

Comment: I would like to start my app every 1 minute

Comment: when the application in background?

Comment: is your code working, what is happen when running this code

Comment: it only starts when you turn on your smartphone, I would like my app I not start every minute

Comment: u mean when the app is in background it is not working

Comment: I would like to open my app on the screen